# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, ecmascript-6

Así como el título, tengo este pequeño error en mi código, y no sé porque la función `JSON.parse()` no me recibe el JSON que envio.

Actualmente uso Firefox, pero he intentado con Chrome (por si acaso) y no funciona, aunque creo que no tiene nada que ver.

pagina1.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Problema</title>
  <script src="funciones.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  Ingresar:
  <form action="pagina1.php" method="post" id="formulario">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="50"> <br>
    Contraseña:<input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" size="6"> <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Ingresar" id='bt1'>
  </form>
  <a href="pagina1.php?cod=0">No tengo cuenta</a>
  <div id="resultados">Your information will show below:<br></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Pienso que estoy enviado de manera errónea los datos a través del metodo `post`, pero no lo creo, ya que estan bien codificados:

funciones.js

```
addEventListener('load',inicializarEventos,false);

function inicializarEventos()
{
  var bt = document.getElementById('formulario'),
      enl = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];

  bt.addEventListener('submit', presionBoton, false);
  enl.addEventListener('click', presionBoton1, false);
}

function codificarDatos() {
  var cad = '',
      name = document.getElementById('name').value,
      pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;

  cad = "name="+encodeURIComponent(name)+"&pass="+encodeURIComponent(pass);

  return cad;
}

var conexion1;
function presionBoton(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  conexion1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  conexion1.onreadystatechange = procesarEventos;
  conexion1.open('POST', 'pagina1.php', true);
  conexion1.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  conexion1.send(codificarDatos());
}

function presionBoton1(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  conexion1 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  conexion1.onreadystatechange = procesarEventos;
  conexion1.open('GET', 'pagina1.php?cod=0', true);
  conexion1.send();
}

function procesarEventos(e) {
  var resultados = document.getElementById('resultados');
  var datos = new Array();

  if (conexion1.readyState == 4) {

    if (conexion1.status == 200) {

      resultados.innerHTML = JSON.parse(conexion1.responseText);

    } else {
      resultados.innerHTML = 'Error de autenticación';
    }

  } else {
    resultados.innerHTML = 'Procesando...';
  }
}
```

Como pueden ver, envio al servidor los datos correctamente y aún así me muestra el error.

pagina1.php

```php
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

  if ( !isset($_REQUEST['cod']) ) {

  } else {
    $code = utf8_encode($_REQUEST['cod']);
    $data;

    $name = utf8_encode($_POST['name']);
    $pass = utf8_encode($_POST['pass']);

  if ($name == 'test' && $pass == 123) {
    $data = '{bug: "when do we solve this bug?", helpMe: "mind"}, ';
  }
  $str = json_encode($data);

  echo $str;
}
```

Nuevamente... Aquí los datos que mando, según yo, no tienen ningún error.

He leído que la función `JSON.parse()`solo recibe datos codificados en `utf-8`, y por lo tanto, he puesto en mi codigo de php la cabecera correspondiente.

Comment: Esto no es JSON correcto: `{bug: "when do we solve this bug?", helpMe: "mind"}, '` Debería ser algo así: `{ "bug": "when do we solve this bug?", "helpMe": "mind"}`. Qué valor tienes en tu variable `conexion1.responseText`? Tiene pinta de que lo que sea que valga, no es JSON correcto.

Comment: Gracias por la brevedad de su comentario. He reparado el JSON por este ```{ "bug": "when do we solve this bug?", "helpMe": "mind"}```, como usted me comentó. Por otro lado ```conexion1.responseText``` recibe el valor de la variable ```$str``` del código de php.

Comment: Las llaves en JSON deben estar encerradas en comillas dobles (`"`, e.g. `"bug"`), tal como lo indica @ArianJM

Comment: Para evitar errores valida tu JSON aquí [Valida JSON](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: @eriicx0 pero puedes copiarnos aquí el valor que hay en `conexion1.responseText`, el error dice claramente que el JSON ha terminado antes de lo esperado. Así que tiene toda la pinta de que `conexion1.responseText` no tiene un JSON completo, y no se puede hacer el `parse` correctamente.

Comment: @ArianJM aquí esta: https://ibb.co/jrPG60G

Comment: @eriicx0 pues ese es el problema, estás intentando hacer `JSON.parse("");` o sea, nada. `conexion1.responseText` no contiene lo que quieres, quizá estés pasando mal del PHP. No sé dónde está el error, lo siento.

Comment: ¿Solucionaste este problema?

Answer (score 0):

El error dice que el JSON pasado a `JSON.parse` termina antes de lo esperado, lo que indica que seguramente tengas un JSON incorrecto.

De tu código, por ejemplo, este JSON no es correcto:

```php
$data = '{bug: "when do we solve this bug?", helpMe: "mind"}, ';

// Este sería el correcto.
$data = '{"bug": "when do we solve this bug?", "helpMe": "mind"}';
```

No puedes tener texto sin comillas dobles (en JSON siempre dobles `"`).

Como comenta Vick Muñoz, puedes validar tu JSON aquí: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Ya lo reparé y todavía muestra el error.

Answer (score 0):

la salida de la pagina1.php debes cambiar la cabezera a:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

y la data, cambiala por un arreglo

```
$data = array( bug => "bug solved", helpMe => "off course");
```

Comment: Hice todo y aún da el mismo error

Comment: tu codigo funciona, tu logica en php esta _rara_ ...
en mi prueba....el parse lo hice `JSON.parse(conexion1.response);`

y como es un objeto en la pagina solo se ve [Object object]

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como yo lo hago, creo un array asociativo, le paso la funcion json_encode y en mi js utilizo JSON.parse(), tal vez el error que tengas es que estas armando un json y a ese json le estas pasando la función de PHP json_encode, ahí habría conflicto, aparte de que el json lo estás armando mal.

```
  if ( !isset($_REQUEST['cod']) ) {

  } else {
    $code = utf8_encode($_REQUEST['cod']);
    $data;

    $name = utf8_encode($_POST['name']);
    $pass = utf8_encode($_POST['pass']);

  if ($name == 'test' && $pass == 123) {


echo json_encode($data = array('bug' => 'when do we solve this bug?', 
                            'helpMe' => 'mind'));
//Yo lo haría de esta manera, creo un array asociativo, lo meto en la funcion json_encode y ya puedo usar JSON.parse() en el JS

  }

}
```

Comment: Copié y pegué tu código y ni aún así.

Comment: @eriicx0 en esta parte `resultados.innerHTML = JSON.parse(conexion1.responseText);` guarda la `conexion1.responseText` en una variable por ejemplo `var parse= JSON.parse(conexion1.responseText);` después para imprimir por ejemplo el **bug** hazlo así `resultados.innerHTML = parse.bug;` comenta si te imprimió el valor que tiene la clave **'bug'**.

Comment: No, no se imprimió. Salé el mismo error

Answer (score 0):

No se está envíando el parametro cod, por lo tanto la siguiente condición en tu código PHP es TRUE:

```
  if (!isset($_REQUEST['cod'])) {
    //Código que se va a ejecutar.
  }
```

Al ejecutarse esa condición como TRUE, no está retornando datos. Coloca el json que deberías retornar al final para comprobarlo.

También ayudaría a que pongas el request que se está generando.

Saludos.

Comment: Hice como me dijo y aún sale el mismo error.

Comment: Cambia el header de la espuesta también. En el código PHP header("Content-Type","application/json").... actualmente está retornando una página HTML..... también podrías la respuesta del script PHP si hacés la petición desde otro programa, cómo CURL.

Comment: Lo he hecho con anterioridad. Así se encuentra mi código: https://ibb.co/Pgcfwnc

Comment: Me he dado cuenta que hay un pequeño error de sintaxis en el código y lo he reparado (https://ibb.co/M18KrSv)... Aún así sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Proba por partes. En el script PHP deja solamente la linea que establece la cabecera y la que escribe los datos..... ese sería el caso en que todo funciones correctamente, luego le agregas las condiciones que necesite.